# Gitlab CI only variables that come from extends

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following setup (simplified version), which doesn't run the expected merge::my when I use tag that includes the string "TEST". I can't figure out why is it happening - I know that only doesn't support variable expansion, but here the variable is just a string, that is being set up in a different extend - is that a problem? Would using yaml anchors be better? Are there different suggestions?

The reason that I check for only:variable in merge_builds is because I have many languages, in this case I used en, but I have many others, and I don't want to do the only:variables for each (the real matching is more complex - I stripped it to bare minimum for the example)

```
.merge_builds:
  script:
    - echo 'test'
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ $VARIABLEMATCH
  
.en_variables:
  variables:
    VARIABLEMATCH: /^$|(?i)EN/

merge::en:
  extends:
    - .en_variables
    - .merge_builds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on GitLab issue [35438](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35438), I'd say that it is not currently possible to use a variable (as opposed to a literal) as the regular expression pattern.

Within issue 35438,  @furkanayhan explains in a comment titled "Introduction" from 2021-09-06 (sorry, I wasn't able to get a permalink to it) that GitLab will make a simple string comparison between a value and a pattern given as a variable:

```
variables:
  teststring: 'abcde'
  pattern: '/^ab.*/'

test1:
  script: exit 0
  rules:
    - if: '$teststring =~ $pattern'

test2:
  script: exit 0
  rules:
    - if: '$teststring =~ /^ab.*/'
```

> The test1 job is not created because the backend makes string comparison between "abcde" and "/'^ab.*/".

> The test2 job is created because the backend makes regexp comparison between "abcde" and /'^ab.*/.

I believe that you are encountering the same behavior that caused "test1 job" not to be created.

However, issue 35438 shows that GitLab is planning on offering a fix in version 15.0, scheduled for 2022-05-22.

One other thing you might want to check on is the regular expression itself.  GitLab's regexp doc ([here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern)) states that GitLab uses the [re2 regular expression syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) for these kinds of comparison.  To achieve case insensitivity, I believe one appends the "i" flag as in:

```
/pattern/i
```